# How to key data containing double quotes using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to key a password containing a special character double quotes. I'm getting a compile time error in Java as expected for code mentioned below.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("cred_password_inputtext"))
  .sendKeys("ghsfdjfsg"ksdkhkh");
```

Comment: does the backslash escaping work in Java? I mean \"

Comment: you get the compile error, because to the compiler it looks like one string `"ghsfdjfsg"` followed by an unexpected tokens `ksdkhkh`. You need to try to escape the quotes with a backslash, i.e. sendKeys("ghsfdjfsg\"ksdkhkh");

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was able execute the following code with backslash driver.findElement(By.id("cred_password_inputtext"))
  .sendKeys("ghsfdjfsg\"ksdkhkh");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use escape character '\' while sending the password. i.e;

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("cred_password_inputtext")).sendKeys("ghsfdjfsg\"ksdkhkh");
```